# Appending to a div in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At first imgButton is a string of text containing HTML for an img tag. However, this variable is later turned into the results of .detach() of the img tag. The problem in the below code is that it does not display the image that it did previously, but instead [object Object] is displayed. It does display the correct image when using imgButton inside of its own append statement or appendTo. Is there a way to print out imgButton in the same append statement as the other strings and have it display properly?

I hope I explained the problem properly.

```
$("#search_prams").append("<div class='advsearchparam'><select class='searchparam'>" +
        "<option value='test'>test</option>" +
        "<option value='test1'>test1</option>" +
        "</select><input class='search' type='text'><button class='remove' id='remove1'>X</button></div>"+ imgButton);
```

Answer (score 2):

If it says that `imgButton` is an `object` then it is not a `string` try this,

```
$("#search_prams").append("your div string here ")
                  .append(imgButton);// append img button here
```

Comment: That is one of the solutions that i mentioned above with having imgButton inside its own .append. But I was wondering if its possible to put it in the same statement with the div string.

Comment: Its not a string if you try `alert(imgButton)` then you will see an `object[object]` type messagein `alert` rather than a `string`.